# How to fix 'beforeNavigate2' in Access VBA

Tags: javascript, vba, ms-access, treeview

I have implemented coolJStree to a webbrowser-element inside my access database. The tree works fine, till I installed the access-database on a local PC of a customer. Now tree is visible and when I click on a Node, it just expand but it dosen´t go into the vba sub (oTree_beforeNavigate2).

```vb
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents oTree As SHDocVw.WebBrowser
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Set oTree = Me!ctlTreeview.Object
    Dim x As Variant
    x = 0
    If x = 0 Then
        GetLoad
        x = x + 1
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub WaitForReady()
    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until oTree.ReadyState >= READYSTATE_INTERACTIVE
End Sub

Private Function GetLoad()
    Dim sURL As String
    Dim sIconPath As String
    Dim sDoc As String
    Dim sMenu As String
    Dim sStyle As String
    Dim f As Integer
    Dim var As Variant
    On Error Resume Next
    oTree.Navigate2 "about:blank"
    WaitForReady
    f = FreeFile
    sURL = C:/ & "tree_template.html"
    Open sURL For Binary As f
    sDoc = String(LOF(f), 0)
    Get f, , sDoc
    Close f
    sMenu = tree_mieter
    sIconPath = var & "icons\"
    sIconPath = Replace(sIconPath, "\", "/")
    sIconPath = "file://" & sIconPath
    sStyle = GetStyleString
    sDoc = Replace(sDoc, "@@@", sMenu)
    sDoc = Replace(sDoc, "???", sIconPath)
    sDoc = Replace(sDoc, "§§§", sStyle)
    oTree.document.write sDoc
    MsgBox sDoc
End Function

Private Sub oTree_BeforeNavigate2(ByVal pDisp As Object, URL As Variant, Flags As Variant, TargetFrameName As Variant, PostData As Variant, Headers As Variant, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Right(URL, 1) = "w" Or Right(URL, 1) = "x" Or Right(URL, 1) = "y" Or Right(URL, 1) = "z" Or Right(URL, 1) = "v" Then
        Dim sRet As String
        Dim N As Long
        N = InStrRev(URL, "\")
        sRet = Mid(URL, N + 1)
        sRet = Replace(sRet, "about:", "")
        Cancel = True
    End If
    If Right(URL, 1) = "v" Then 'Ansprechpartner
        URL = Left(URL, Len(URL) - 1)
        URL = Right(URL, Len(URL) - 6)
        DoCmd.BrowseTo acBrowseToForm, "frm_1", "frm_main.frm_main_sub_main", "asp_id = " & URL
    Else
        If Right(URL, 1) = "z" Then 'Unternehmen
            URL = Left(URL, Len(URL) - 1)
            URL = Right(URL, Len(URL) - 6)
            DoCmd.BrowseTo acBrowseToForm, "frm_2", "frm_main.frm_main_sub_main", "adr_id = " & URL
        Else
            If Right(URL, 1) = "y" Then 'Gebäude
                URL = Left(URL, Len(URL) - 1)
                URL = Right(URL, Len(URL) - 6)
                DoCmd.BrowseTo acBrowseToForm, "frm_3", "frm_main.frm_main_sub_main", "geb_id = " & URL
            Else
                If Right(URL, 1) = "x" Then 'Liegenschaft
                    URL = Left(URL, Len(URL) - 1)
                    URL = Right(URL, Len(URL) - 6)
                    DoCmd.BrowseTo acBrowseToForm, "frm_4", "frm_main.frm_main_sub_main", "ls_id = " & URL
                Else
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I expect, that after click on a node, it goes to oTree_beforeNavigate2, but he don´t but only on the pc of the customer. Usually it works.

Comment: `sURL = C:/ & "tree_template.html"` ??

Comment: @Tim I just changed that for showing